# How can I extract double values of a string without space, just characters for identification

Tags: c#, string, extract

I am working on a plugin for CAM software and one of the methods is to extract the data, double values, from the CNC machine file `.txt` that the software generates.
An example of it would be: `N0310X3.6849Y0.9048Z-0.1656`

The values I'm looking for are the ones followed by: X, Y, and Z. Those are coordinates.
I need to find a way to extract those values, knowing that the lines may not have all coordinates or even any of them.
I thought of using a loop to iterate each character and a lot of if conditions to copy to another string. I see that this is a terrible way, but couldn't manage to think of anything else.

Normally the lines would have a space between the commands and for that, I already found an easy way to handle the values.

Comment: How should I interpret it, as N0310 `X3.6849` `Y0.9048` `Z-0.1656`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using *regular expressions* in order to *match* name / value pairs:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

  ...  

string text = "N0310X3.6849Y0.9048Z-0.1656";

var result = Regex
  .Matches(text, @"(?<name>\p{L}+)(?<value>-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)")
  .Cast<Match>()
  .Select(match => (
     name : match.Groups["name"].Value,
     value : double.TryParse(match.Groups["value"].Value, out var v) ? v : double.NaN))
  .Where(pair => !double.IsNaN(pair.value))
  .ToArray();
```

Pattern `(?<name>\p{L}+)(?<value>-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)` explained:

```
(?<name>\p{L}+) named group where
   name        - group has name "name"
   \p{L}+      - one or more unicode letters 
(?<value>-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?) named group where
   value       - group has name "value"
   -?          - optional -
   [0-9]+      - one or more digits in 0..9 range
   (\.[0-9]+)? - optional group (fractional part):
     \.        - decimal separator
     [0-9]+    - one or more digits in 0..9 range
```

Let's have a look:

```
Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

Output:

```
(N, 310)
(X, 3.6849)
(Y, 0.9048)
(Z, -0.1656)
```